# Sqlite3 UPDATE FROM (VALUES) syntax error

Tags: sql, sqlite, join, sql-update, common-table-expression

I'm trying to use a query for updating rows in my table with key-value pairs. So the row where column-value is *key* updates with *value*.
For this I tried to use:

```
UPDATE access_keys 
SET global_id=a.global_id 
FROM access_keys 
INNER JOIN (VALUES (1,123),(2,321)) as a(id, global_id) 
on a.id = access_keys.id WHERE a.id = access_keys.id;
```

And

```
UPDATE access_keys 
SET global_id=a.global_id 
FROM (VALUES (1,123),(2,321)) as a(id, global_id) 
WHERE a.id = access_keys.id;
```

In both cases I get:

> near "(": syntax error (1)

Where is my error? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQLite does not support aliasing columns that come from a subquery using `VALUES`.

You can use the aliases `column1`, `column2`:

```
UPDATE access_keys AS ak 
SET global_id = v.column2 
FROM (VALUES (1, 123),(2, 321)) AS v
WHERE v.column1 = ak.id;
```

Or, simpler, use a CTE:

```
WITH cte(id, global_id) AS (VALUES (1, 123),(2, 321))
UPDATE access_keys AS ak 
SET global_id = c.global_id 
FROM cte AS c
WHERE c.id = ak.id;
```